# media css3 is not working on safari browser

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, safari, media-queries

I am customizing bootstrap for 3>>2>>1 columns display on browser resize or small devices. I have used css3 media query which is working on all browser except Safari. Following is css i have used. It's always using the first media query and because of that it is causing issue on Safari. I have tested both Mac and Window Safari and faced same issue. Please help.

**Viewport Added in HTML head section**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

**CSS3 Used:**

```
/*Apply different margin based on media size*/
@media (min-width:1632)
{
.two-column .row-fluid [class*="span"]:nth-child(3n+1)
    {
        margin-left:100px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 981px) and (max-width: 1631px)
{
    .two-column .row-fluid [class*="span"]:nth-child(2n+1)
    {
     margin-left:100px;
    }

}

@media (min-width: 982px) and (max-width: 1155px)
{
    .two-column .row-fluid [class*="span"]:nth-child(2n+1)
    {
     margin-left:10px;
    }

}

@media (min-width: 545px) and (max-width: 981px)
{
    .two-column .row-fluid .span6  
    {
     margin-left:5%;
    }

}


@media (max-width: 546px)
{
    .two-column .row-fluid .span6  
    {
     margin-left:5px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using a unit in the first media query? e.g. `@media (min-width: 1632px)`

Comment: omg....what a blunder mistake i had. I was keep looking my code to find out silly mistakes since last two weeks however couldn't find.....thanks for your observation. Its working now :-)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap explicitly do not support Windows Safari as stated in their browser support docs.

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean the page won't work at all on Safari. They also don't mention the Linux versions of Firefox and Opera on their website, but there really is no discernible difference in how Bootstrapped pages behave between those and the Windows versions.

Comment: Agreed. We should not by what is supported or not ...we should stick to basics standard and then see what is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the 'px' after @media (min-width:1632)

```
@media (min-width:1632px)
```

This should fix it.